# Subtracting Time (Hours) By Next Day

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms

I'm having a bit of an issue where trying to subtract (using `DATEDIFF`) two times from one another and produce a total amount of hours.  This isn't an issue mostly however, sometimes the subtracted date would be leaked over into the next day - so the start date would be something like 7/30/2014 - 10 AM and the end date would be 7/31/2014 at 6 AM and then I would get a negative number.

Currently I'm doing something like this

```
DATEDIFF (hh,CAST(saa.Time as DATETIME),CAST(saa.DepartureTime as DATETIME)
```

I just want to know how I could avoid something like this? I would like the answer to be in hours but do I need to create some sort of condition? First subtract days and if Day > 0 then do something? lol

Also note that saa.Time and saa.Departure time are given in DateTime

```
saa.Time                | saa.DepartureTime
-------------------------------------------------
2014-07-30 10:00:08.097 | 2014-07-31 06:15:12.018
```

Comment: Do you have *Time* only? if you use, `DECLARE @datefrom AS DATETIME = '7/30/2014 10:00:00:00' DECLARE @dateto AS DATETIME = '7/31/2014 06:00:00:00' SELECT DATEDIFF(hh, @datefrom, @dateto)`, it works fine.

Comment: What does your data actually look like?  Do you only have **TIME**?  If so, have you tried seeing what happens when you cast time to datetime?

Comment: Actually the saa.Time is a DateTime input and so is saa.DepartureTime

Comment: @StayPuft for your example you get -4?

Comment: Exactly - and I'm not sure why - even after using the DATETIME

Comment: Should I not include DATETIME since the info is already in datetime??

Answer (score 2):

If you get a negative number then that is because your values are purely times and not full date_time values.

You should include the date in the value in order to factor in the date difference.

This could be

datediff (day,saa.Date,saa.DepartureDate) * 24 +

--This multiplies the day difference by 24 to give me the number of hours...

datediff (hh,saa.Time,saa.DepartureTime)

For example.

I think you are saying that the above doesn't answer your query.

The difference is a negative number - do you want to show the number without negative sign?

So use ABS() e.g. 
`SELECT ABS(-1.0), ABS(0.0), ABS(1.0)`

Comment: Actually the saa.Time is a DateTime input and so is saa.DepartureTime - and as noted in the above - I tried using DateTime for the Datediff